# Using THREE.js with aurelia-cli, exporting as global

Tags: three.js, aurelia

Install THREE.js: `npm install three`

Configuring `aurelia.json`:

```
"dependencies": [
      {
        "name": "three",
        "path": "../node_modules/three/build",
        "main": "three.min"
      }
```

importing in view: `import * as THREE from 'three';`

Ok so this works and I am able to use `three.js`, however, I would also like to use some of the plugins. Specifically `GPUParticleSystem`. Now this plugin depends on a Global `THREE` object. In a first attempt I added this to `aurelia.json`

```
"dependencies": [
          {
            "name": "three",
            "path": "../node_modules/three/build",
            "main": "three.min",
             "exports": "THREE" //this should make the library a global object?
          }
```

But it doesn't seem to be working? I cannot see the global variable from devTools.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way of solving this is to use `prepend` in `aurelia.json`:

```
...
"prepend": [
    "node_modules/three/build/three.min.js",
    "node_modules/three/examples/js/GPUParticleSystem.js"
 ]
...
```